# VBA copy values from one array and store them into another

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am hoping to find help with this current VBA problem. I have looked throughout Stack Overflow and other Google searches, but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Essentially, I have a user pasted value on my page which I am delimiting on a comma, and then storing that into an array. What I am aiming to do is then loop through that array and eliminate any extra spaces, and then also delete any values that AREN'T a number.

1. Copy user values
2. Store into an array
3. Erase whitespace

So far, I have not been able to:

4. Copy items that ARE a number to new array

Currently, my code looks like:

```
Sub grabText()

' This macro was written as a test macro to grab and filter data entered in a textbox

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim enteredValue As String ' Value taken from page
    Dim vals() As String ' Array once it is split
    Dim goodvals() As String 'Formatted array
    Dim i As Integer 'Index

    enteredValue = ActiveSheet.myTxt.Text
   ' MsgBox enteredValue

    vals() = Split(enteredValue, ",")

    lastitem = UBound(vals)
   ' MsgBox lastitem

    'Formats array
    For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
        i = TRIM(vals(i))
        '
        '   If (ISNUMBER(vals(i)) == TRUE) Then
        '       enter i into goodvals()
        '
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. I was thinking about ways to do this in other languages (Java, Python) and I was thinking about Linked-Lists.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues:

- Don't assign the result of `Split` to `vals()`, but to `vals`
- Don't re-use the variable `i` for the result of the `Trim`. It is better to use a separate variable for that, which you can then type as a `String`

You can capture the desired result if you

- First reserve enough room for your target array: it can never be longer than the `Split` result, so use that as the initial size
- Use a separate index variable for referencing the target array index, and only increment it when you have stored a number in it
- Finally reduce the size of the target array to the size that was actually used

Code:

```
Dim enteredValue As String ' Value taken from page
Dim vals() As String ' Array once it is split
Dim goodvals() As String  'Formatted array
Dim i As Long 'Index in vals
Dim j As Long 'Index in goodvals
Dim s As String 'Individual string

enteredValue = ActiveSheet.myTxt.Text

vals = Split(enteredValue, ",")
' Reserve as many entries in the target array
ReDim goodvals(UBound(vals))

j = LBound(goodvals)
For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
    s = Trim(vals(i))
    If IsNumeric(s) Then 
        goodvals(j) = CDbl(s)
        MsgBox goodvals(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next

' Shorten the array size to the part that is used
If j Then
    ReDim Preserve goodvals(j - 1)
Else ' There were no numericals at all, so erase the array:
    Erase goodvals
End If
```

Comment: this is awesome!! Thank you so much! I am doing my best to understand it, and think that I do.

However, could you explain the following:
'If IsNumeric(s) Then 
        goodvals(j) = CDbl(s)
        MsgBox goodvals(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If'

If the captured number is numeric (and not a "-" or "///___dsdf"), then??
Sorry, I am just trying to understand!

Comment: If it is numeric, then the string value (that is numeric) is converted to a number. There are several functions available for that, but `CDbl` (**C**onvert to **D**ou**bl**e Precision Floating Point Number) will also treat decimal numbers, like "9.3". The `MsgBox` is only for showing what is happening -- you can of course remove that line. `j = j + 1` prepares for an eventual next number that must be added, so that it does not overwrite the value you just added to the result.